# jQuery onclick function is not executing

Tags: jquery, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

I am finding the latitude and longitude of an address entered by a user. I am calling a jQuery function on button click of a form. But the controller method is executed before this jQuery function. What I want is when a user clicks the submit button, the jQuery function is called after the success controller function is called.

**View:**

```
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">           </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function getCoordinates() {
           $("#sumbitBtn").click(function(){
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': '#street' }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    alert("location : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + " " + results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                    $(selector).val(value)
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    $('latitude').val('latitude');
                    $('longitude').val('longitude');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {

                            mylat: latitude,
                            mylang: longitude
                        },
                        url: "RentOutSpace/AddSpaces",
                        success: function (result) { success(result); }
                    });

                } else {
                    alert("Something got wrong " + status);
                }
            });
           });
    }
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddSpace","RentOutSpace","$.post()"))
{


@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please correct the errors and try again")

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.latitude)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.longitude)
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.street)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.street)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.street)
        </div>

    <input type="submit" value="submit"  onclick="getCoordinates()" id="sumbitBtn"/>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
          [HttpPost]
          public ActionResult AddSpace(RentOutSpace rentModel, string lati, string lang)
          {
           rentModel.latitude = lati;
           rentModel.longitude = lang;


        Session.Store(rentModel);
        Session.SaveChanges();
        return View();
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just reading your code it seems that it's executing. You set up just another event handler:

```
function getCoordinates() {
    $("#sumbitBtn").click(function(){
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        ...
}
```

I think that you have to remove that line

```
$("#sumbitBtn").click(function(){
```

and closing `});` to get it working.

**Update:** This is minimal test to show error in your code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getCoordinates() {
    console.log('onsubmit called!');
    $("#sumbitBtn").click(function(){

        console.log('$("#sumbitBtn").click() deleted!');
    });
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"  onclick="getCoordinates()" id="sumbitBtn"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Loading this code and pressing submit button you will get message in console window:

```
onsubmit called!
```

To get it running properly and have second message displayed (it is instead of `geocode()` functions, you have to remove `$("#sumbitBtn").click(function(){` and closing part. After that we will get two messages:

```
onsubmit called!
$("#sumbitBtn").click() deleted!
```

If your code doesn't work after changes that means there is another error.

Comment: I removed these line but getCoordinates() function is not executing

Comment: What is `$(selector).val(value)` in `geocode()` part?

Comment: I am setting the value of hidden textboxes name laitude and longitude to values of coordinates i get from geocoding so i can pass it to controller to save it in db.

Comment: If you put `console.log('onsubmit called!');` after `function getCoordinates() {` line, do you get message logged into console after submit button is pressed or not?

Comment: function is executing by the method explained by Wilmer but lat and long values are not posting to controller

Comment: `$('latitude').val('latitude');` should be `$('latitude').val(latitude);`. similar for the next line.

Answer (score 1):

First you have your function:

```
function getCoordinates() {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': '#street' }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    alert("location : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + " " + results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                    $(selector).val(value)
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    $('latitude').val('latitude');
                    $('longitude').val('longitude');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {

                            mylat: latitude,
                            mylang: longitude
                        },
                        url: "RentOutSpace/AddSpaces",
                        success: function (result) { success(result); }
                    });

                } else {
                    alert("Something got wrong " + status);
                }
            });

            return false;//prevent form submit
    }
```

Then you can attach it the javascript way on the element onClick:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit"  onclick="getCoordinates()" id="sumbitBtn"/>
```

Or the jquery way on a separate file/section:

```
$(function(){//when the document is ready
    $("#sumbitBtn").click(getCoordinates);
});
```

Comment: thanks function is executing now but latitude and longitude values are not posted to controller.

Comment: Ok great, but that seems to be related to google maps now. Maybe create a different question?